# R loop through columns in data table - possible setnames() bug?

Tags: r, loops

A for loop is used to select each column of a data table by changing the column name to "selcol" using `setnames()`.  In the full code, each column is used multiple times for a varying number of people who apply to the column criteria.   Then the column name is changed back to its original name.  This is where there seems to be a bug, because `setnames()` is changing the column name in more places than the data table specified.  Further the `setnames()` function does not change the column name back.  If instead of using a loop, I set the index y=1, y=2, ... then this bug does not occur; it only happens when running the loop.  I've tried defining a temporary table, and I've tried defining a vector of column names, but when I use `setnames()` in these objects the name is changed in the permanent table and in the vector of names that should stay constant.  I tried a data table and a data frame.  I'd like to know if this is a bug in the package, and is there another practical way to select each column?

```
norows = 5
nocols = 7

mtrx_perm <- as.data.table(matrix(round(rnorm(norows*nocols), digits = 3), ncol = nocols, byrow = T))

colnames(mtrx_perm) <- as.character(seq(0:6)-1)

resetnames <- colnames(mtrx_perm)

vect_temp = rep(0, norows)
for (y in 1: nocols){
mtrx_temp <- mtrx_perm
setnames(mtrx_temp, as.character(y-1), "selcol")
vect_add <- mtrx_temp$selcol
#setnames(mtrx_temp, "selcol", as.character(y-1))
colnames(mtrx_temp) <- resetnames
vect_temp <- vect_temp + vect_add
}

mtrx_perm
mtrx_temp
vect_temp
apply(mtrx_perm, 1, sum)
```

Comment: Why are you using a data.table structure if you're not using data.table syntax?

Comment: Do you mean the code should read   ` vect_add <- mtrx_temp[, selcol]`?  This does not change the error / bug.

Comment: I am just curious, because there seems to be no benefit to using the *data.table* package here.

Comment: Or do you mean looping through `DF[, y]` or `DF[, as.character(y)]` ?  In the for loop I was getting errors when putting the loop index inside the square brackets, so I attempted to select DF$selcol.  Sometimes R seems to like a changing data frame index and sometimes it does not read it.  I am using data.table in the full code but the same error exists for a data frame.

Comment: Can you show what your desired output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `data.table` but it seems that `setnames` changes the names in both `mtrx_perm` and `mtrx_temp` I assume it has something to do with how `data.table` changes things in place. Anyways I replaced `setnames` with `colnames` and it works fine

```
library(data.table)
norows = 5
nocols = 7

mtrx_perm <- as.data.table(matrix(round(rnorm(norows*nocols), digits = 3), ncol = nocols, byrow = T))

colnames(mtrx_perm) <- as.character(seq(0:6)-1)

resetnames <- colnames(mtrx_perm)

vect_temp = rep(0, norows)
for (y in 1: nocols){
  mtrx_temp <- mtrx_perm
  colnames(mtrx_temp)[y] <- "selcol"
  vect_add <- mtrx_temp$selcol
  colnames(mtrx_temp) <- resetnames
  vect_temp <- vect_temp + vect_add
}

mtrx_perm
mtrx_temp
vect_temp
apply(mtrx_perm, 1, sum)
```

I also don't get why you are selecting a column by changing its name? Why not just iterate over the column names more directly? You show that you know the better way of solving your example using `apply` so can you create an example that shows what about your use case requires a loop?

Comment: This notation does work and to change back the column name `colnames(mtrx_temp)[y] <- as.character(y-1)` so the bug is solved.  When I iterate over the column names directly in data table notation I sometimes only get the first element of the column.  But that problem only occurs when in a loop.  Now that I can isolate each column one at a time, and return the column names to original, I do not have any questions about the full code as that seems run as expected.  That is why I have excluded the notion of the full code from the example.

Comment: Okay that's fine it just seems like something where there might be a better (more "R like") way to solve your overall problem. Generally if you are using a for loop in R there is a better way to do it. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-on-loops-in-r  skip to the part about alternatives

Comment: My issue is resolved although there seems to be some interest in refining the code so I will describe it.  A list of # of actual patients by age group by year is given.  Code distributes groups to distinct ages 0 - 85 (max); then the column selected is average life expectancy for the age, discrete by year; so if there are 8 patients age 31 in 1990, 8 random #'s are generated and 8 records are added to a new data frame for 1990, age 31, with the 8 projected ages at death.  The loop was quick to write, avoids needing lists of different lengths and gives the clean output desired.  Improvements?